Horizontal Line Artifacts in Point Cloud Image from Helios 2+ Depth Camera
I have a Helios2+ Depth Camera mounted on top of a gripper connected to a cobot, the cobot moves randomly around a center position in a set range and takes snapshots, totaling 5000 snapshots. When viewing the .ply files (I use a Python script) some images contain horizontal line artifacts.
Image containing artifacts:
Snapshot
About 1/100 .ply files contain these artifacts.
Image without artifacts:
Snapshot
I suspect it has something to do with the network in my office, but I'm not really sure. The camera is connected via Ethernet, and we do have a busy network environment.
Has anyone encountered similar issues with point cloud data from depth cameras? Could this be related to network interference or something else? I'd be happy to provide further information. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.
We've tried resetting the camera and server, but not the whole network. Leaving the camera to take snapshots resulted with the same artifacts the day after.
